# postman retrieve an empty response when i post json field to my api

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

So i want to build an api, and in the tags field i want to add several values. Something like this:

[image]

But when i get the response, the fields are inserted succesfuly except the tags field that is empty:

> {"id":1874,"name":"Juan
> José","surname":"Castaños","dni":"123122193S","address":"calle
> izquierda,12","mail":"castaños@juan.com","phone":"673482212394","created_at":"15/04/2021","updated_at":"16/05/2021","linkedln":"https://www.linkedin.com/in/sara-b-54b93543/","state":"por
> validar","rating":"98","availability":"mañanas","tags":[]}]

Im building a spring jpa app with angular front.

This is my expert model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="experts")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String created_at;
    private String updated_at;
    private String linkedln;
    private String state;
    private String rating;
    private String availability;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="expert", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();


    public Expert() {
    }

    public Expert(String name, String surname, String dni, String address, String mail, String phone, String created_at, String updated_at, String linkedln, String state, String rating, List<Tag> tags, String availability) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.address = address;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
        this.linkedln = linkedln;
        this.state = state;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.availability = availability;
    } //getters and setters
```

my tag model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
           name = "experts_tags",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="expert_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
   )
    private List<Expert> expert = new ArrayList<>();
```

this is how i persist my data in expertDAO:

```
 @Override
    public Expert postExpert(Expert expert) {
         this.manager.persist(expert);
         return expert;
    }
```

why is my json not being recognized?? thanks you a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the Expert class, on the many to many relationship you have marked the cascade type as MERGE. Also your code only calls the persist method for the Expert type objects. There is no way Hibernate will know the Tags collection should be persisted.

You can do 2 things:

- Remove the cascade declarations and manually persist the tag entities.

OR

- Use a different cascade type, such as ALL or PERSIST.

Also, I consider a bad practice to put the cascade declarations on both entities. Usually cascading makes sense if there is a parent-child relationship, and the parent entity should control how cascading works.

Comment: If it helped, consider upvoting and marking as a answer. :)

Comment: i did but as i dont have enough karma isnt registred. If its ok for you you will consider contact me for solve me more doubts? Im doing a project with rigid deadlines and i need help! obviously if we fix a price we both agree